# Problems with ScrollView and Flexbox

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox, scrollview

I tried to add ScrollView to my component but it doesn't work as I need it to. It moves everything to the top.

This is my screen before adding ScrollView, I need the screen to look like this, but with the scroll option:
[image]

This is my screen after adding ScrollView:
[image]

And this is my code:

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollview} scrollEnabled={scrollEnabled} onContentSizeChange={this.onContentSizeChange}>
    <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
      <View style={[styles.petNameContainer]}>
        <Text>{this.state.petInfo.name}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.petProfileContainer}>
        <Text style={{textAlign:'left'}}>{this.state.petInfo.race}</Text>
        <Image style={{height:100, width:100}}
          // en local --> source={require('../assets/images/homescreen/Avatar.png')}>
          source={{uri:this.state.petInfo.url_image}}
        />
        <Text style={{textAlign:'right'}}>{this.state.petInfo.species}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.foodBar}>
        <Image style={{height: 40, width:250}}
          resizeMode="stretch"
          source={require('../assets/images/homescreen/Comida.png')}>
        </Image>
      </View>
      <View style={[styles.prueba]}>
        <Text>15:30 - Última entrada del log</Text>
        <Text>21:30 - Próxima comida.</Text>
        <Text>Icono + Historial de comidas</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={[styles.quarterHeight]}>
        <Image
          style={{height: 40, width:250}}
          resizeMode="stretch"
          source={require('../assets/images/homescreen/Agua.png')}>
        </Image>
      </View>
      <View style={[styles.quarterHeight]}>
        <Text>15:30 - Última entrada del log</Text>
        <Text>Icono + Historial de agua</Text>
        <Text>15:30 - Última entrada del log</Text>
        <Text>Icono + Historial de agua</Text>
        <Text>15:30 - Última entrada del log</Text>
        <Text>Icono + Historial de agua</Text>
        <Text>15:30 - Última entrada del log</Text>
        <Text>Icono + Historial de agua</Text>
        <Text>15:30 - Última entrada del log</Text>
        <Text>Icono + Historial de agua</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
    </ScrollView>
```

Styles:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
mainContainer: {
  flex: 1,
  flexDirection: 'column',
  justifyContent: 'space-between',
  alignItems: 'center',
  flexWrap: 'wrap'
  },
  petNameContainer: {
  flex: 1,     
 },
 quarterHeight: {
  flex: 1,
},
prueba: {
flex:1
},
petProfileContainer: {
flex: 1,
flexDirection: 'row',
alignItems: 'center',
justifyContent: 'space-between',
flex: 2,
marginTop: -95 
},
foodBar: {
flex:1
}
});
```

I'm new to React Native, so I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I cannot see the styles of scrollview. Which you have defined as styles.scrollview . Just add flexGrow:1 to styles.scrollView style object. I also have no idea why you have used flex:1 for many objects. It is unnecessary in point of my view but only you know what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just remove the `marginTop: -95` from your `petProfileContainer` style.